# Docker exited with Code 0 on running docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, mindsdb

Below are my files.

**DOckerFile**

```
    # Python support can be specified down to the minor or micro version
    # (e.g., 3.6 or 3.6.3).
    # OS Support also exists for jessie & stretch (slim and full).
    # See https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/ for all supported Python
    # tags from Docker Hub.
    FROM python:3.7.3
    
    LABEL Name=mindsdb Version=0.0.1
    
    WORKDIR /app
    ADD . /app
    
    RUN  pip install mindsdb

**Docker Compose**

version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: mindsdb
    image: mindsdb
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - /path/to/mindsdb:/app/
    # tty: true
```

When I enable `tty: true`, it shows the following and gets stuck.

```
Creating mindsdb ... done
Attaching to mindsdb
mindsdb | Python 3.7.3 (default, May  8 2019, 05:28:42) 
mindsdb | [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
mindsdb | Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

By enabling verbose in `docker-compose up` shoes below:

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach -> <generator object socket_raw_iter at 0x104116f68>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start <- ('4511f48c4370b53c2f0cbe9f9c6479ebd9f76ad9426f315ef288dbdea947ed5f')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/4511f48c4370b53c2f0cbe9f9c6479ebd9f76ad9426f315ef288dbdea947ed5f/start HTTP/1.1" 204 0
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start -> None
Starting mindsdb ... done
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: app>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
Attaching to mindsdb
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=mindsdb', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)
mindsdb | Python 3.7.3 (default, May  8 2019, 05:28:42) 
mindsdb | [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
mindsdb | Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dmindsdb%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <generator object APIClient._stream_helper at 0x1041913b8>
```

I don't get why it is getting inside the Python shell. Even `docker run -v /path/to/mindsdb:/app/ -i -t python:3.7.3` is doing similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have a "[CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)" or "[ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)" set in your Dockerfile.

Those two commands will tell the Docker what to execute when entering the docker.
The reason you're seeing the python shell is probably because that's the default ENTRYPOINT or CMD for the "python:3.7.3" docker that you are inheriting at the start of your Dockerfile..

Comment: OK, makes sense. My main objective is to use the required version of Python and could use the interpretator by logging into it. What should I do?

Comment: I added `CMD [ "python", "./fetch.py" ]` ,it still shows the same.

Comment: How about running the docker like this:
"docker run -v path/to/code:/app mindsdb"

Comment: It is exiting right away. And when I add `-it` it shows main Python image entry point

Comment: Can't see why it wouldn't work.. Have you rebuilt your docker after adding "CMD"?

Comment: OK I built again it does run but python does not execute file due to path issue and says no file and directory

Comment: That just means that your file (fetch.py) is not in the correct location.
Does the "fetch.py" file exist within "path/to/code"? If not, you need to modify your "path/to/code" so that fetch.py is in the root. That way, the file will be in "/app/" inside the docker and you'll be able to execute it